# Close a subprocess that was opened in a new window in python

Tags: python, batch-file, subprocess

I have a .BAT file that runs a python script that can take many hours to finish, (I need to end it after a maximum of x hours)

I am trying to find a way to schedule this using python.

My idea was to Create a .PY that will initialize this .BAT file, then put a time.sleep, the somehow close that .BAT that was previously started.

```
subprocess.Popen('C.bat', creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
time.sleep(14400)
'''Somehow close the above started .BAT'''
```

I would then have to wrap this in a while loop to have it repeat.

Answer (score 1):

you can close it by pid

```py
process = subprocess.Popen('C.bat', creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
time.sleep(14400)
os.killpg(os.getpgid(process .pid), signal.SIGTERM)
```